# existe forma de trabajar con sessiones o cookies sin una base de datos?

Tags: javascript, php

Buenas, necesito crear un simple formulario login. Se supone que tengo que trabajarlo sin base de datos, y una vez que el login me acepte me redireccione a la pagina **home.php**, pero no se puede acceder directamente a **home.php**. Pero me dijeron que tenia que hacerse sin base de datos, lo cual no me cuadra, ya que se como controlar las sesiones con php, porque trabajo con una base de datos, pero en este caso no debo implementarla. Alguna idea?

Comment: si no puedes usar una base de datos, controla el acceso simplemente en el if que usas para realizar el logueo.

Comment: ¿No sirve tener todos los Login y el hash de sus passwords en un archivo de texto? Lo cargas en un mapa y chequeas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La base de datos se usa como repositorio de datos. Cualquier otra forma de repositorio puede servir. Un .txt o un .json son suficientemente útiles. Por ejemplo se puede tener claves.json

```
 { "pepe": "xkdkasdfjasdfsfasdf3234asfd",
   "claudia": "jasfasa39939d98asv88hz8d8f"
 }
```

Y en vez de buscar en la base de datos buscar en el archivo .json

```
 $claves_json = file_get_contents("claves.json");
 $claves = json_decode($claves);
 //... obtener del cliente $usuario y $clave luego:
 if($clave == md5($claves[$usuario])){
     // ok, entrda correcta
 }else{
     // mal, 
 }
```

### md5

**Nunca almacenes claves planas** en una base de datos ni en un txt. Hay que tratar de mantener la privacidad del usuario. Muchas personas usan la misma clave para muchos sitios, guardar la clave sin hashear (por ejemplo con md5) puede ser un problema de seguridad si alguien te hackea el sitio y se lleva la base de datos o el archivo de claves.

Answer (score 1):

Como te han dicho, nunca guardes contraseñas en texto plano, pero tampoco te recomiendo md5 ya que hay miles de "traductores" de md5, utiliza en hash de php

```
<?php
/**
* En este caso, queremos aumentar el coste predeterminado de BCRYPT a 12.
* Observe que también cambiamos a BCRYPT, que tendrá siempre 60 caracteres.
*/
$opciones = [
  'cost' => 12,
];
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $opciones)."\n";
?>
```

fuente: http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 0):

El formulario login, al enviarse, puede ir a un archivo intermedio, por ejemplo door.php, el cual no tiene salida a pantalla. En este archivo recibes los datos del formulario y los comparas con las cadenas de usuario y contraseña que deben estar ahí mismo en el door.php. Si coinciden, haces un header location a home.php. Si no coinciden, lo puedes regresar mediante otro header location al formulario con algún mensaje. Para asegurar el archivo home.php puedes hacer bastantes cosas, como requerir una variable de sesión que se creó en el door.php, o un condicional que hace que si el home.php no tiene un referral (una página que lo llamó), destruya la sesión y lo mande al login.